# Limit number of notifications in scheduler

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have an cold observable and an observer.
Both are slow but the observer is slower than the observable.
They process many and many notifications so I don't want to store notifications without limit.

This sample takes about 30 seconds to complete. Very slow. I believe they can do in 21 seconds.

```
var subject = new Subject<int>();

subject.Subscribe(i =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss} - {i}");
});


Task.Run(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss} - Start");
    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        subject.OnNext(i);
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss} - End");
});
```

This sample finishes about in 20 seconds but the observable ends before the observer shows "4".
It indicates the scheduler stored 4 to 9 somewhere. I afraid if it stores over 1'000'000 notifications and throws OutOfMemoryException.

```
var subject = new Subject<int>();

subject.ObserveOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance).Subscribe(i =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss} - {i}");
});


Task.Run(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss} - Start");
    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        subject.OnNext(i);
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss} - End");
});
```

That's why I want to limit number of notifications in the scheduler.

**edit: diagram**

```
x : calculate or other task
S : send notification
R : receive notification

-- time -->

sample1
thread1:  xxxS       xxxS       xxxS
thread2:     Rxxxxxx    Rxxxxxx    Rxxxxxx

sample2
thread1:  xxxSxxxSxxxSxxxSxxxSxxxSxxxS
thread2:     RxxxxxxRxxxxxxRxxxxxxRxxxxxx

I want
thread1:  xxxSxxxS   xxxS   xxxS   xxxS
thread2:     RxxxxxxRxxxxxxRxxxxxxRxxxxxx
```

Comment: Limit the number, as in is it okay if you discard some notifications?

Comment: No, I want sender to stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try implementing a custom `IScheduler` that throttles the requests (the method `Schedule`) using a [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim).

Alternatively you could create a `BlockingThrottle` extension method that accepts and returns an `IObservable`, that you could chain to the original `IObservable` before subscribing to it. Here is an implementation that uses a [`BlockingCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) as a throttling mechanism:

```
private static IObservable<T> BlockingThrottle<T>(this IObservable<T> source,
    int boundedCapacity)
{
    return Observable.Create<T>(observer =>
    {
        var queue = new BlockingCollection<T>(boundedCapacity);
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var locker = new object();
        Exception exception = null;

        new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var item in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable(cts.Token))
                {
                    observer.OnNext(item);
                }
                observer.OnCompleted();
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                Exception ex; lock (locker) ex = exception;
                if (ex != null) observer.OnError(ex);
            }
            // Leave all other exceptions unhandled.
            // The responsibility for catching them belongs to the caller.
        })
        { IsBackground = true }.Start();

        var subscription = source.Subscribe(x =>
        {
            try
            {
                queue.Add(x, cts.Token);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { } // Ignore this exception too
        }, ex =>
        {
            lock (locker) exception = ex;
            cts.Cancel();
        }, () =>
        {
            queue.CompleteAdding();
        });

        return Disposable.Create(() =>
        {
            cts.Cancel();
            subscription.Dispose();
        });
    });
}
```

Usage example:

```
subject.BlockingThrottle(boundedCapacity: 10).Subscribe(i =>
```

---

**Note:** If you are planing to use this inside an ASP.NET application, consider replacing the `BlockingCollection` with an async queue (like a `BufferBlock<T>` or a `Channel<T>`), to avoid blocking threads.

Comment: This sample worked very well. I have not known `BlockingCollection`. In this sample, exception thrown by `observer.OnNext` is catched and passed to `observer.OnError`. Is it OK?

Comment: @v..snow I am not completely sure. It seems reasonable, otherwise an exception at this invocation will remain unobserved. Another option would be to catch and swallow the exception so that the `foreach` loop can continue, but I don't like swallowing exceptions. Are there any other options?

Comment: I thought `OnError` is where processes error from observable. So I don't think it's good behavior. In case of `Subject` exception in `observer.OnNext` back to `subject.OnNext`, but this option is not available in this case. In case of `ThreadPoolScheduler`, the exception go to UnhandledException. It looks good, but I have no idea how to implement this.

Comment: @v..snow you are right. The behavior of other similar built-in methods like the `Delay` is to propagate an exception at `OnNext` as unhandled. So these callbacks are behaving like event handlers. The subscriber must ensure that all errors inside the event handler are caught, otherwise an unhandled exception will surface. I'll update my answer soon to mimic this behavior.

Comment: I replaced the `Task.Run` with a `new Thread`, so that the exceptions remain unhandled. Also fixed two holes in the cancellation logic.

Comment: Added error handling inside the `onNext` callback too, just to be sure...

Comment: I got that I have to use Thread directly to unhandle.   I noticed another issue that `observer.OnNext` may be called after `observer.OnError`, but it's not serious for me and easy to guard.

Comment: You seem more experienced with RX than me. I studied this library very recently. :-)

Comment: I hope that its a robust solution. Writing extension methods for `IObservable`s is trickier than writing extension methods for `IEnumerable`s. Maybe some expert RX user could find holes in this code, or provide a different, better solution.

Comment: +1 The solution is great. 
But the underlying problem is that of a consumer lagging the producer. If you remove the `Task.Run` from outside the loop and do `Task.Run(() => { subject.OnNext(i); });`, the problem returns. I fear how well this works depends on his particular implementation.

Comment: @Asti if you `Task.Run` every call to `subject.OnNext`, then you'll end up with multiple blocked thread-pool threads, waiting for available space in the internal bounded queue of the `BlockingCollection`. :-)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yep.  It'll spin up more threads, but eventually you run out of threads for other tasks in your program as well.

Comment: @Asti sure. But this is what the OP wants. They want a way to block the producer, to prevent the case of an `OutOfMemoryException`. Is there any way to block the observable without blocking at least one thread?

Comment: I agree with you. I have a feeling co-routines are better suited to this job than Rx.

Comment: @v..snow now I understand what you mean with *observer.OnNext may be called after observer.OnError*. It is against the [Observable Contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html)! I updated my answer so that all notifications are coming from the spawn thread (with the intention of being serialized).

Comment: I was absent. This process would be started only one or some in my program so I accept wasting some threads. It might be better to use `IAsyncEnumerable` but My company will not buy VS2019! (never blame. we are not system developer)

Answer (score 2):

The Rx contract requires that notifications are *serialized*, so even though you may specify a `Scheduler`, it's more akin to saying "here, use this scheduler for managing concurrency".

`ThreadPoolScheduler` will still serialize the notifications, so the end result is that it won't call your method in parallel.

If you want asynchronous execution, you could rewrite it to this:

```
subject.Subscribe(async i =>
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss} - {i}");
});
```

But the underlying problem is that your consumer lags behind your producer.
You could look into using [backpressure](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/backpressure.html), or if your application is a series of data processing tasks, you could also look into the excellent TPL Dataflow.

What happens in that pipeline between the source of events and its final sink, that's where Rx shines best.

Comment: Probably I have to use backpressure. Is it available in C# Rx?

Comment: It isn't. Discussion at https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/19

Comment: You could also try `IAsyncEnumerable` in C# 8.